# iTunes Callback

Tags: api, itunes

Hi anyone know if there is a way to check if an item has been purchased on itunes? and if so, get information about the item?

For example

user goes to site and purchases song/video etc

purchase goes through

find out what item was purchased, any codes or ID associated and who buy?

can't find any info on google about it, not sure if this info is available from a purchase

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.**

Apple is actually *very* protective of user data - especially the sensitive stuff. People don't really want just any app to be able to view their entire iTunes purchase history - and Apple knows that.